# Regex that has apostrophe in the middle of the word but not at the start or end of the word

Tags: regex, string, scala, symbols

I want my regex to detect string like

```
abc'
'abc
```

and

```
'
```

And not detect something like:

```
ab'c
```

How can I achieve this. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

[EDITED]

How do I say in regex:

Take this pattern `(?:(^\\w+'\\w+))` and match any other occurrences of `'`

That is ignore `ab'c` and then match all occurrences of `'`

Comment: something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/tS7bP3/1)? This is assuming a lot from your question though

Comment: You cannot negate a sequence properly with a Java regex. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
^'|'$
```

Answer (score 1):

`(^'.*)|(.*'$)` should work,  or at least in my tests it did.

Answer (score 0):

To match apostrophe on a word boundary:

```
scala> val r = """\b'|\b'""".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = \b'|\b'

scala> def f(s: String) = r.findAllMatchIn(s).map(_.start).toList
f: (s: String)List[Int]

scala> f("ab'")
res0: List[Int] = List(2)

scala> f("ab' c'd 'ef")
res1: List[Int] = List(2, 5)
```

gives the distance from the last match.